# When connecting 3 switch in Spanning tree, Should I use Switch port or SFP ports?

Tags: cisco, switch, spanning-tree, sfp

I have 3 Cisco switches. Should I use standard switch ports or SFP ports for spanning tree? What are the benefits to using the SFP ports?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

Spanning-tree is spanning-tree no matter which ports you use.

Answer (score 2):

spanning-tree is used in all ports in switch but if you use the SFP port, don't need to configure again and again if there is a fault in the sfp port u simply change the SFP module ( FIBER or COPPER).This Is the benefit u gain from SFP Port.

Comment: Another advantage,  ports with pluggable optics tend to be faster;  faster ports should be used to uplink to other switches (and thus run stp on them)

Answer (score 2):

The first question has been answered, but I'd like to elaborate on the second.

> What is the benefits of using SFP port?

There is no benefit to using an SFP port for spanning tree.  Spanning tree protocol runs over ethernet there is no difference (to the switch) between the ethernet of the copper 1000base-T and fibre-optic 1000base-SX (or LX) connection.

Of course, if you're doing a run that's over 100m to the next switch you'll need to use the SFP slot and make the connection over fibre but spanning tree will act the same that way as it would if the next switch is connected with a 10m cat-5e cable.

Comment: There is at least one BIG difference between copper and optics - copper link lost detect time can take up to 750 ms (optics have less time). it is important in topologies that uses STP. http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/solutions/Verticals/CPwE/CPwE_DIG/CPwE_chapter3.html (look on fig 3-11)

Comment: i am sorry, my comment has a mistake - fig. 3-11

Comment: @pyatka, you can edit your own comments...

Comment: @CraigConstantine, yep, i know ;-) and usually it`s work... but now the button("pencil" sign below my comment), is not clickable. may be it is somekind of timeout